# Как сделать "закидывание файла в программу" VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Как сделать открытие файла закидыванием его в окно приложения? Делаю приложение на VisualStudio, используя язык программирования C#.

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/walkthrough-performing-a-drag-and-drop-operation-in-windows-forms)

Comment: это называется drag & drop, смотрите как оно реализуется для вашего типа приложения - для WinForms и для WPF оно немного отличается, но идея одинаковая.